# How do I convert a black and white pixel image to text?

Tags: python, image

I have a png file with black pixels on a white background. I was trying to find a way to convert it to a binary value text file.

That is to say, I want a way to turn a 4 pixel, black and white png that looks like

XX
OX

into text that reads like

11
01

The best lead I had was installing PIL, but either I didn't install something right or this doesn't do what I think it does since I get a "name 'pix' is not defined" error.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("image.jpg")
fil = open('file', 'w')
pixel = im.load()
row, column = im.size
for y in range(column):
    for x in range(row):
        pixel = pix[x,y]
        fil.write(str(pixel) + '\n')
fil.close()
```

any helps or leads would be appreciated

Comment: You get this error because you try to get `pix` value in the line `pixel = pix[x,y]` but you did not identified `pix` in your code. Perhaps you wanted to write something like this instead: `p = pixel[x, y]`.

Comment: Your title says "convert to text" but your question says "convert to binary". Neither of these is completely well-defined. Do you mean convert the binary image into a textual representation of the pixels' RGB values? Or something like [PBM format?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) Or actually OCR?

Answer (score 0):

pix is indeed not defined. You saved your PixelData into your 'pixel' variable, thats where the pixels are stored.

You can get each pixel with: pixel[x,y] not pix[x,y].
Try replacing

```
fil.write(str(pixel) + '\n')
```

With:

```
fil.write(str(pixel[x,y]) + '\n')
```

You could store a pixel in a variable like you did at

```
pixel = pix[x,y]
```

But for that, you have to name the variable something else, since pixel is the name of your PixelData variable.
You could do it like this:

```
pix = pixel[x,y]
fil.write(str(pix) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code that converts black and white image to binary text:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('<path-to-image>/bw.png').convert('L') #this is needed to convert the image to grayscale. PIL by default opens it as RGB.

np_img = np.array(img)
np_img[np_img > 0] = 1
print(np_img) # prints the binary text in matrix
```

More reference: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html